# Channeling traffic through proxy in iOS app

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine, proxy

I have a Unity iOS app which I need to have a built-in proxy to access some IPs which are banned by some ISPs. I'm looking for a way to start a proxy session at the start of my app to channel the traffic and access these banned ips. I wanted to ask if there are any ways to do this in preferably in Unity c# or in XCode objective-c. 
Thanks